# Force biblatex to print initials of the author even in the following citations

Tags: biblatex

The default biblatex verbose-ibid style prints the initials of the author the first time you cite the work, and the following times it only prints the name.

Example : 
`Filler texte\footcite{ex}. Filler text\footcite{ex}.`
gives the footnotes

> 1. BLACK, J., *Title of work*, Address, Publisher, Year.
> 2. BLACK, *Short title of work*.

I would like to make biblatex print the initial also the second time, i.e. obtain

> 1. BLACK, J., *Title of work*, Address, Publisher, Year.
> 2. BLACK, J., *Short title of work*.

Does anybody have an idea of how to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}`, but you will lose all `uniquename` capabilities that way. (Mind you they are probably already diminished by only using initials.) If you want to retain them, a more complicated redefinition `\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}` is needed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best to redefine `labelname` as follows

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}=2%
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \else
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

This will always print at least the first name initials and more if need be (obviously only with `uniquename` properly set).

A shorter definition would just be

```
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}
```

where we lose `uniquename` abilities (that are already diminished thanks to `firstinits=true`).